# TFS 2018 API - Generate PAT or SSH

Tags: tfs, ssh-keys

I would like to generate SSH public key or Personal Access Token using the TFS API. Is there any way to do that? I searched through the documentation of the API on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) but I didn't find what I am looking for. We are currently using TFS 2018 Update 2.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no such an API to generate PAT or SSH for now. There is a related [user voice submitted here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34561156-rest-endpoint-to-generate-pat), you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future. You can also submit a new user voice to suggest the feature.

- For now we can only generate the PAT via web portal and the PAT will
  be displayed only once.

  You will need to copy it and store it somewhere safe, so that you can
  retrieve it as needed.

  > Make sure you copy the token now. We don't store it and you won't be
  >   able to see it again.
- To generate and use the SSH public keys you can refer to [Use SSH key
  authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts) for details.

[image]